# China Z visa: what happens if I quit the job during probation period?

Tags: visa, employment, china

I have changed my plans and I don't want to work in China. It is my probation period and I want to quit in 3 days. I did not get a residence permit and I came here on the 10th of October with a Z visa.

Can I leave the country if the duration of stay on this visa says 000 days, which means I am required to get the residence permit within 30 days after entry? What if I fail to get the residence permit and want to leave China within 30 days? Is it possible to leave the country?

Comment: Just make absolutely sure you follow the correct exit procedure for China otherwise you will denied a new VISA should you ever want to come back.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a problem leaving as long as it's within the 30 days.
It shouldn't matter why you did or didn't move forward with the expected job.
The Z visa just means you have the right to enter and look for work.  Many Z visa holders enter with a job contract already, but I believe that's not strictly the meaning of the visa.

I would leave by the 29th day so there's no room for discussion.